# Any way to simplify a removeData() chain?

Tags: jquery

At the moment, I'm removing multiple data values from an `id` with

```
$("#id")
.removeData("Test1").removeData("Test2")
.removeData("Test3").removeData("Test4");
```

Is there any way to simplify this?

Some things I've tried are

```
$("#id").removeData( "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" "Test4" );
```

and

```
$("#id").removeData( { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4" } );
```

I've been playing around with this for a bit but haven't found a solution, if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up more readable and maintainable than the alternative for our application. Looks like you could just pass an array.  Nice.

`var testArr = [ "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4" ];
$("#id").removeData(testArr);`

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/#removeData-list), `removeData()` takes "An array or space-separated string naming the pieces of data to delete."

So either:

```
$('#id').removeData("Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4");
```

or

```
$('#id').removeData([ "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4" ]);
```